# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces

How do I add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package Namespace to my VS 2012 project?
I can't find it inside "Assemblies". Should it be downloaded separately?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This namespace exists across a number of Visual Studio DLLs including

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.10.0.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.11.0.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.9.0.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.dll

Instead of focusing on which namespace to use focus on the type.  What DLL the type resides in will have a much more definitive answer

Comment: I don't have any of them. Nothing that starts with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.*

Comment: @user990635 they are all a part of the Visual Studio 2012 SDK.  Have you installed that on your machine?

Comment: Thank you. Just installed Visual Studio 2012 SDK. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Language Service references I'm using with Visual Studio 2015. All can be installed from Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.14.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.12.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.14.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.12.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0
```